# No instructor for 2 months

Tags: contract-law, malpractice

Does anyone know or have any information on school malpractice? I'm currently in my 6 month of trade school and for the last 2 months they have not had an instructor for us. The instructor is supposed to be on campus every Saturday and Sunday. Also online Tuesday and Thursday for zoom meetings, going over all the subject matter. Me and several of the other students in my class have met up at the school during the week to meet with several different "higher ups" on several different occasions to resolve this matter and they keep saying "we're working on it." I'm paying out of pocket and I'm curious if there's a possible solution or route that I0 can take? I've brought transferring to a different school to HR and she immediately said that she personally couldn't help me but that she would "pass" the message to the President of the school and he would get back to me. Which is what they all keep saying...

Comment: What state is the trade school in? You're bound by the contract you signed to enroll, but that contract should also stipulate conditions of faculty conduct. And, the state the school is in may have regulations governing trade schools.

Comment: I'm in Arizona.